# remove template in renderTemplate ember route after loading is finished

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router, ember-components

i made a loading view when the route has to much waiting for the data, this is my route

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '../../config/environment';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  desaService: Ember.inject.service(),
  model(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      currentlyLoading:true,
      desas: this.get('desaService').find(ENV.defaultOffset, ENV.defaultLimit),
      desaCount: this.get('desaService').count()
    });
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('backend.master-desa').set('desas', model.desas);
    this.controllerFor('backend.master-desa').set('currentlyLoading', model.currentlyLoading);
    this.controllerFor('backend.master-desa').set('desaCount', model.desaCount);
  },
  renderTemplate(controller, model){
    let controller2 = this.controllerFor('backend.master-desa');
    if(controller2.get('currentlyLoading')){
      this.render('components/common/loading-view', {
        into:'application'
      });
    }
  },
  actions:{
    loading(transition, originRoute){
      let controller = this.controllerFor('backend.master-desa');
      controller.set('currentlyLoading', true);
      transition.promise.finally(function() {
        controller.set('currentlyLoading', false);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

first i set currentlyLoading true, then the renderTemplate will be called and showing 'components/common/loading-view' into application.hbs.
this is work but i need to remove that 'components/common/loading-view' after the loading actions has complete.
please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [disconnectOutlet](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_disconnectOutlet) method of router. What you need to do is to call the following to remove the template that is rendered within `renderTemplate` hook method.

```
  actions:{
    loading(transition, originRoute){
      let _this = this;
      let controller = this.controllerFor('backend.master-desa');
      controller.set('currentlyLoading', true);
      transition.promise.finally(function() {
        controller.set('currentlyLoading', false);
        _this.disconnectOutlet({
          outlet: '',
          parentView: 'application'
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

However, if you run your application probably you are going to see that nothing is rendered. Here is the reason:

`renderTemplate` hook is run after `model` is already solved; hence you will see nothing until the model is fully resolved. `renderTemplate` hook will be run to make a rendering; however `loading` event within actions will be fired and you will remove the template that is about to be rendered since loading is finished. Hence, you will not achieve what you want with this design approach.

You need to is to render something before `model` is fully resolved; and that is explained in the [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) specifically. I suggest you to go over it and ask more if you run into some issues.

I have prepared the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a62a22498d3021ff40a872e7306f1f65?openFiles=templates.index.hbs%2C&route=%2Fmy-route) for you that illustrates both usage of a `loading` template to show until `model` is fully resolved and usage of `disconnectOutlet` to remove a template that is rendered to a specific `outlet`. I hope this will help you understand better. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You doing it wrong, [read the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/). All you need is to create a `loading.hbs` file and put html for loading screen there.

Also, if you want to create a loading indicator that will be displayed while assets are loading and application is starting, you can use [this addon](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-load)

Also, Your `setupController` can be simplified to `controller.setProperties(model);`. [setProperties doc](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_setProperties)